# AndEngine - do I try to use a little atlas as possible?

Tags: android, performance, graphics, 2d, andengine

I've been studying AndEngine and am taking up developing an application used AndEngine GLES2 cannot find information on reated to this question.

should I use a separate atlas for each group of sprites?

Or try to pack as many sprites as possible onto as little atlas as possible relative to what options i want the atlas to have etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not AndEngine specific, but universally if you want to support as many devices as possible, you should opt for-

1. Have a maximum of 1024 by 1024 spritesheet/textureatlas.
2. Make sure your spritesheet's width and height are a power of 2. (e.g. 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc)
3. Try packing all sprites that belong to one scene/stage into one texture atlas. This will help in performance because switching from one texture to another one during draw/render is NOT good. But it is usually not possible to have all the game sprites packed in one spritesheet because you have your game sprites, game fonts, maybe some parallax images, etc. In your render call, draw first all the sprites that belong to one spritesheet, then move to another one. For instance, if you have a font atlas, a parallax atlas, and a game sprite atlas; draw first the parallax, then game sprites, and then the font. Bottomline is minimize texture switching.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use multiple texture atlases, say one for background image(s), one for item sprites, and another for player sprites, then you shouldn't always make them 1024 x 1024. This uses overhead and will slow processing time. I also suggest using a `BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas` as this will prevent texture bleeding. With these, you do not have to place the TextureRegions on the atlas by coordinate, it is handled for you. It can be implemented like this:

```
    BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas = 
new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.mEngine.getTextureManager(), 128, 128);
```

Then you can add your `ITextureRegions` to it like this:

```
// Notice, you do not have to supply x and y coordinates..it is handled for you :)
    ITextureRegion mTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                              .createFromAsset(this.mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas, 
                               this, "your_image.png");
```

Then you can add the `ITextureRegion` to your `BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas` like this:

```
// You must use a try/catch statement to build this type of Bitmap texture atlas.
try {
   // Use a BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder to prevent the texture from bleeding. We will add some padding.
   this.mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 1));
} catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Now that it is built, it can be loaded.
this.mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
```

More information can be found [here](http://srcrr.com/android/AndEngine/GLES2/2012.03.27/reference/org/anddev/andengine/opengl/texture/atlas/bitmap/BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas.html)

Comment: I know how they work :) It was more relevant to whether I try to cut down the number I use for a performance gain and if it is worth doing, sorry for the lack of information

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I didn't mean to insult :(

Comment: It is better for performance if your atlases aren't oversized. If you need to add more texture regions, you could always go back and increase the size of the atlas (up to 1024 x 1024, not all devices can handle much bigger than that). I would set the size of your atlas with a final int, that you can manually modify at the top when you need to.